# Screen keeps Loading forever

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

So I just started Working with Sencha Touch 2 and I am already running into some issues. I am currently working through the getting started tutorial but then I'm stuck because after I've made some changes and refresh the page, the loading screen just keeps loading non-stop. This prevents me from moving forward with the tutorial because not matter what I do, it just keeps loading. I tried creating a new project but then run into the same issue again. Can anyone help with this? I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any errors being logged in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because you must have something in your code that throws an error and therefore prevent the application from executing properly.

Maybe you should try to debug it with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

Hope this helps